# Couldn't load target `NOTRACK':No such file or directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cilium

I am trying to add a IP table rule.

iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j NOTRACK

But when I am executing this I am getting below error:

iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load target `NOTRACK':No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

This target is deprecated and has been superseded by the [`CT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#CT) target. So I'm not surprised to see a system where support for this target was not built (in kernel) anymore.

> [`NOTRACK`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#NOTRACK)
>
> This extension disables connection tracking for all packets matching
> that rule. **It is equivalent with `-j CT --notrack`.** Like `CT`, `NOTRACK` can
> only be used in the `raw` table.

You can replace the rule with:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j CT --notrack
```

If then this also doesn't work, you'd have to check exactly what support for iptables targets exist (eg: in `/boot/config-*`) or if there are additional restrictions on the host system.

Relevant kernel options:

- [`CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK.html)

  > CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK: 'NOTRACK' target support **(DEPRECATED)**
- [`CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CT`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CT.html)